JarSigner Keyset does not exist
I am facing problem when changing algorithm to new one.
When executed with old algorithm, I got jar signed:
D:\Buildtools\zulu17.52.17-ca-jdk17.0.12-win_x64\bin\jarsigner.exe -storetype Windows-ROOT -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -sigfile SigFileName -tsa http://timestamp.digicert.com D:\JenkinsData\workspace\plugin\target\plugin-37.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar "Friendly name"
Output is:
 jar signed.

 Warning: 
 The SHA1 algorithm specified for the -digestalg option is considered a security risk and is disabled.
 The SHA1withRSA algorithm specified for the -sigalg option is considered a security risk and is disabled.
 POSIX file permission and/or symlink attributes detected. These attributes are ignored when signing and are not protected by the signature.
 
 The signer certificate will expire on 2024-11-19.
 The timestamp will expire on 2031-11-10.

When executed with new algorithm I got an error.
D:\Buildtools\zulu17.52.17-ca-jdk17.0.12-win_x64\bin\jarsigner.exe -storetype Windows-ROOT -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA256 -sigfile SigFileName -tsa http://timestamp.digicert.com D:\JenkinsData\workspace\plugin\target\plugin-37.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar "Friendly name"
Output is:
 jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.security.SignatureException: error 2148073494, Keyset does not exist

Running on Windows Server 2022 Standard
Can anyone point me to direction what is problem with this change. I am suprised, that changing parameters will end with not working signing.
